# Port forwarding on Vagrant 1.8.1

Tags: vagrant

I have a vagrant installed on Windows7 PC. I have jenkins, puppet other stuff installed on my centos7 vagrant box. When I do vagrant reload

```
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 8082 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
GuestAdditions 5.0.12 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/vagrant/projects/jenkins
    default: /vagrant_data => C:/Devops
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `-
provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will
still run.
```

Now when I do curl -v

```
C:\>curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8082
* Rebuilt URL to: http://127.0.0.1:8082/
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8082 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8082: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8082: Connection refused
```

Needless to say http://127.0.0.1:8082 doesnt fetch anything in the browser wither. What am I missing? BTW my vagrant and virtual box 5 is running on Windows7.

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: can you confirm you have something running on 8080 from the vm and you do not have firewall on centos, and if you have make sure to allow connection on 8080 from external

Comment: I have jenkins listening on 8080 (on centos). how do I allow connection on 8080 from external? I have already flushed iptables on cetnos. Thanks

Comment: try running `systemctl disable firewalld`

Comment: @Frederic.Thanks a lot, I did disable the firewall, it doesn't work.